# change position of an element smoothly

Tags: jquery, html, css

When scrolling down a page, I want to smoothly move the menu to the top of the page and change its position to sticky. With following code, I can make the menu fade in when scrolling.

How can I make it to smoothly move up and then stick there instead of suddenly fadein?

Here's my code:

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){

    var menu = $('#menu'),
        pos = menu.offset();

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if($(this).scrollTop() > pos.top+menu.height() && menu.hasClass('default')){
                menu.fadeOut('fast', function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('default').addClass('fixed').fadeIn('fast');
                });
            } else if($(this).scrollTop() <= pos.top && menu.hasClass('fixed')){
                menu.fadeOut('fast', function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('fixed').addClass('default').fadeIn('fast');
                });
            }
        });

});
```

**CSS:**

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: -5px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/ZzzxL/

Comment: [How's this?](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/ZzzxL/1/)

Comment: @Pete you should apply your example as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the fadeouts from your jquery function, you should achieve what you are wanting:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > pos.top+menu.height() && menu.hasClass('default')){
        menu.removeClass('default').addClass('fixed');
    } else if($(this).scrollTop() <= pos.top && menu.hasClass('fixed')){
        menu.removeClass('fixed').addClass('default');
    }
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/ZzzxL/1/)